# how to insert into mysql database with java

Tags: java, mysql

i want to insert inputs i take from user into mysql database the connection is right but the insertion gives me error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''u_fname',
>   'u_lname', 'u_uname', 'u_pass', 'u_age', 'u_adderess') values('20','o'
>   at line 1

My code is:

```
public void adduser(User s) {
   try {
        sql = "insert into users ('u_fname', 'u_lname', 'u_uname', 'u_pass', 'u_age', 'u_adderess')"
                + "values('" + s.getFirstname() + "','" + s.getLastname()
                + "','" + s.getUsername() + "','" + s.getPassword() + "','" + s.getAge() + "','" + s.getAdderss() + "')";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        if (i > 0) {
            System.out.println("ROW INSERTED");
        } else {
            System.out.println("ROW NOT INSERTED");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to learn prepared statements. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. And SQL, too: column names must not be quoted.

Answer (score 6):

To insert into mysql, follow these steps-

1. Create a Java Connection to our example MySQL database. *I believe you already took care of it. It will be something like this-*

   ```
     String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
     String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";
     Class.forName(myDriver);
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "");
   ```
2. Create a SQL INSERT statement, using the Java PreparedStatement
   syntax. *Your PreparedStatement SQL statement will be as following this format-*

   ```
     String sql = " insert into users (first_name, last_name, date_created, is_admin, num_points)"
       + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
   ```
3. Set the fields on our Java PreparedStatement object. *It will done as-*

   ```
     PreparedStatement preparedStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     preparedStmt.setString (1, s.first_name);
     preparedStmt.setString (2, s.last_name);
     preparedStmt.setDate   (3, s.date_created);
     preparedStmt.setBoolean(4, s.is_admin);
     preparedStmt.setInt    (5, s.num_points);
   ```
4. Execute a Java PreparedStatement.

   ```
     preparedStmt.execute();
   ```
5. Close our Java MYSQL database connection.

   ```
     conn.close();
   ```
6. Catch any SQL exceptions that may come up during the process.

   ```
     catch (Exception e)
     {
     System.err.println("Got an exception!");
     // printStackTrace method 
     // prints line numbers + call stack
     e.printStackTrace();
     // Prints what exception has been thrown 
     System.out.println(e); 
     }
   ```

Comment: i followed your steps but i got an exception "null" i cant figure out what is the problem in my insertion  code exactly

Comment: Instead of printing the exception message, you better print the exception itself. Some exceptions don't have good messages. Anyway +1

Comment: @OmarMohamed....that is why I have written "any SQL exceptions that may come up". I am editing my answer.

Comment: `executeUpdate()` would be a tick better.